# All/the all/all the

Tags: meaning

Imagine you are asked whether the three sentences you have been exposed to are correct. You want to say that they are correct. You could say:

> All the sentences are correct.
>
> All of the sentences are correct.

But would it be correct to say:

> The all sentences are correct.

or

> All sentences are correct.

I personally think that "the all" is not correct. But I can't explain why.

**All sentences are correct.** - sounds as if I mean all sentences which exist are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The all sentences are correct" is bad grammar  "All" is a determiner and a [pre-determiner](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/predeterminer).  But it can't be placed after another determiner like "the".

"All sentences are correct"  (without further context) is good grammar but false.  It says that every sentence that ever existed is correct.  (It may be possible in some contexts in which there is some understanding of the sentences under discussion)

Comment: OK. Would it be correct to say "All are correct?" To mean "All the sentences are correct?"

Comment: Thats fine, as a reply to a question.